# How to prove the equivalents of the fact that $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The problem is to prove that

> if $f$ is a finite function on $\mathbb{R}^n$, show that
>   \begin{align}
> f \text{ is continuous on } \mathbb{R}^n&\Longleftrightarrow f^{-1}(G) \text{ is open for every open } G\subset\mathbb{R}^1\\
> &\Longleftrightarrow f^{-1}(F) \text{ is closed for every closed } F\subset\mathbb{R}^1
> \end{align}

---

I've finished proving that $$f \text{ is continuous on } \mathbb{R}^n \Longleftrightarrow f^{-1}(G) \text{ is open for every open } G\subset\mathbb{R}^1$$

---

However, I've failed to extend to prove that $$\Longleftrightarrow{}f^{-1}(F) \text{ is closed for every closed } F\subset\mathbb{R}^1$$

---

Can someone prove either upper or lower proposition among two?
\begin{align}
f \text{ is continuous on } \mathbb{R}^n
&\Longleftrightarrow f^{-1}(F) \text{ is closed for every closed } F\subset\mathbb{R}^1\\\\
f^{-1}(G) \text{ is open for every open } G\subset\mathbb{R}^1
&\Longleftrightarrow f^{-1}(F) \text{ is closed for every closed } F\subset\mathbb{R}^1
\end{align}

Comment: What is a "finite" function? And why do you want the proof of the statement with open subsets, if you have already proven it yourself?

Comment: @AlexM. Oh my mistake. I edited my post. Finite function means that $-\infty\lt{}f\lt\infty$ for all domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's prove that $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed for every closed $F \subseteq \Bbb R$ if and only if $f^{-1}(G)$ is open for every open $G \subseteq \Bbb R$.

If $G$ is open then $\Bbb R \setminus G$ is closed, so $f^{-1} (\Bbb R \setminus G) = f^{-1} (\Bbb R) \setminus f^{-1} (G) = \Bbb R^n \setminus f^{-1} (G)$ is closed by assumption, so $f^{-1} (G)$ is open.

Conversely, if $F$ is closed, then $\Bbb R \setminus F$ is open, so $f^{-1} (\Bbb R \setminus F) = f^{-1} (\Bbb R) \setminus f^{-1} (F) = \Bbb R^n \setminus f^{-1} (F)$ is open by assumption, so $f^{-1} (F)$ is closed.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for a nice proof.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: use that if $A$ is open, $A^C$ is closed!

Comment: Is it enough to say that: $CG$ is closed and $f^{-1}(CG)=\mathbb{R}^n - f^{-1}(G)$ is closed on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: What CG means? $G^C$?